# How do I reference the class of classes identified using the wildcard in Java?

Tags: java, class, generics, wildcard

For example, say I wanted to write a method to switch the first two elements of a list, but only if the second is greater than the first. I initially tried to do something like:

```
static void swapFirstTwo(List<? extends Comparable> list) {
    if(list.get(0).compareTo(list.get(1)) > 0) {
        ? temp = list.get(0);
        list.set(0, list.get(1));
        list.set(1, temp);
    }
}
```

Obviously this wouldn't work, but how should I do it? I could replace the `?` with `Object`, but then that's not nice because I would have to do type-checking afterward to make sure everything was safe.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Answer (score 5):

You can give the type up front, then use it:

```
static <T extends Comparable> void swapFirstTwo(List<T> list) {
// ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------------------^
    if(list.get(0).compareTo(list.get(1)) > 0) {
        T temp = list.get(0);
// -----^
        list.set(0, list.get(1));
        list.set(1, temp);
    }
}
```

More in the [bounded section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html) of the Generics tutorial.

As [user7 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136258/how-do-i-reference-the-class-of-classes-identified-using-the-wildcard-in-java/49136371#comment85277726_49136371), we want to put the bound on `Comparable` as well:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> void swapFirstTwo(List<T> list) {
// -------------------------^^^
```

Comment: (I probably should have used `E` rather than `T` in this specific case, standard for list elements...)

Comment: You would get an unchecked warning if you have just `Comparable` (raw type)- Preferable to have `Comparable<E>` or `Comparable<? super E>`

Comment: @user7: Indeed, I didn't fix everything. I probably should have.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use unnamed capture to declare new variables, you can capture the type:

```
static <E extends Comparable<E>> void swapFirstTwo(List<E> list) {
    if(list.get(0).compareTo(list.get(1)) > 0) {
        E temp = list.get(0);
        list.set(0, list.get(1));
        list.set(1, temp);
    }
}

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("world");
list.add("hello");
System.out.println(list.get(0)+" "+list.get(1)); // world hello
swapFirstTwo(list);
System.out.println(list.get(0)+" "+list.get(1)); // hello world
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/aQCEwJ)

Comment: You're right, `E` would be the more typical name for the type in this case, not `T`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Right, I copied this part from OP's code. This is now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bounded type parameter

```
static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void swapFirstTwo(List<E> list) {
    if(list.get(0).compareTo(list.get(1)) > 0) {
        E temp = list.get(0);
        list.set(0, list.get(1));
        list.set(1, temp);
    }
```